# Excel - working with multiple workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, merge

Got about 50 workbooks that cannot be merged but need to make the data available in a nice easy way.  Aany ideas how to open and close multiple workbook modally i.e control remains in some interface / menu window?  all workbooks have multiple sheets and need to be opened read-only.  thanks

Comment: Do they all have the same structure?  Are you trying to summarize / find data within them?

Comment: What do you mean they can't be merged?  Why not run a script to merge them into a separate read-write workbook?  Why would you want to open 50 workbooks all at once - that doesn't seem nice and easy.  Give us more info.  If it were me I would merge 50 workbooks into one workbook, one worksheet per workbook.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need to access the data from all your workbooks in one sheet.

You can use the following syntax to access the value of a cell in an arbitrary workbook/sheet.

```
=[workbookname.xlsx]sheetname!$D$10
```

Here's [a link for more information](http://www.appscout.com/2008/11/reference_another_workbook_in.php).

Comment: +1 That definitely does sound like a more logical approach than opening 50 workbooks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the simplest to use is a good program launcher.

The article [Best Free Program Launcher](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-program-launcher.htm) lists many free launchers (see also the comments).

After a quick look at some screenshots, maybe your best bet is [8start Launcher](http://www.8start.com/), but as I said this was after taking a (too?) quick look.